# How do I type chinese in a text box

Tags: php, html

How do I type chinese in a textbox.

I tried to set the accept-charset in the form to `accept-charset="Big5"` but it does still shows english characters.

I have this

```
<form accept-charset="Big5" encoding="Big5" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="test">
 <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

and my question why does it stil shows english character while typing.

Comment: Google translate and then copy & paste!

Comment: :P Nothing better than google translate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your **IME** to Chinese IME.

Comment: @Daric The input method. As a suggestion, using `UTF-8`, and the world wide user would input what ever they like.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably with a Chinese keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You type Chinese in a textbox like you type it elsewhere. The tools for it depend on the system and aren’t basically a programming issue. For example, in many systems, you can enable an input mode where you type in text in pinyin and then select among its Chinese-character equivalents.

The `charset` parameter has nothing to do with this. It specifies the character encoding used in form data transmission. And it is usually better to use UTF-8 for that on web pages, rather than Big5.